# replicate title on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am shaving this page:

http://67.202.78.104/KLZWeb/defaultAjax.aspx?act=GetvPage&ItemID=2242

I want to take the title and reapply in the details.

Currently the result comes only with the details without the name, for example:

[image]

my code:

def parse(self, response):

```
for site in response.css('div.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4'):
            # ('div.LabelMore'):

    qtd = site.css('div.LabelMore::text').extract()#[3]#.split(' ')[1]

    ##Qtdade
    print('>>>>>>>>>>',qtd)
    #
    if ' ' in qtd:
         qtd = None
    else:
         qtd = qtd[-1].split(' ')[1]

    ### Nome
    nome = site.css('div.DetailInfoName.hc::text').extract()


    yield {

     'nome': nome,
     'qtd': qtd,
     'unimed': 'Slabs',

     'cliente': 'Klz Stones',
     'UF': 'TX',
     'site': 'http://klzstone.com/',
     'inventario': 's',

     'data': date.today()

     }
```

Comment: if you use `css` then you have to use `dot` instead of `space` in class `.DetailInfoName.hc`. `css` treats `DetailInfoName` and `hc` as two classes and both need `dot`. Space is used to separates tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `CSS` then you have to use `dot` instead of `space` in class `.DetailInfoName.hc`.

`CSS` treats `DetailInfoName` and `hc` as two classes and both need `dot`.

`Space` in `CSS` is used to separates tags.

```
nome = site.css('div.DetailInfoName.hc::text').get()
```

Comment: unfortunately, still not bringing the name and reapplying to the details
I tried extract too

Comment: I tested it with `scrapy shell <url>` and `response.css('div.DetailInfoName.hc::text').get()` and I get `'Zimbabwe Black 3cm'`. Maybe you have something wrong in other place. You should put minimal working code so we could run it.

Comment: yes, no scraped shell returns, but I want this title to apply to all descriptions on the page

Comment: eu coloquei o código fora do loop e funcionou